# How to use *args in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in python3, I have a copy of Learn Python the hard way version 1.0 and I have this code in page 45 (code for python2) but when I run it I get this Error: expected an indented block. Can someone explain how it goes wrong.

```
def print_two(*args):
arg1, arg2 = args
print("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to indent the body of your function:

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))
```

Python functions have no explicit `begin` or `end` (like Pascal has), and there are no curly braces to mark where the function code starts and stops (like C has). The only delimiter is a colon (`:`) and the indentation of the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

The body of a defined function in python is determined by indenting.

So you need:

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))
```

The indents tell python that the two lines after the "def" line are the body of the function.

The error you are getting is telling you that there are no indented lines defining the body of the function -- after the "def" line, at least one indented line is expected.

The error is not, as far as I see, related to the use of "args".